# Differences between the podiobook and paper version of Max Quick: The Pocket and the Pendant

Tags: continuity

Mark Jeffrey's [Max Quick: The Pocket and the Pendant](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061988928) was original published as a [podiobook](http://www.podiobooks.com/title/the-pocket-and-the-pendant/).  I listened to the podiobook several years ago, and recently read the paper version.

Jeffrey has said that MQ1 required substantial rewrites, many of which set things up for the two sequels better than the original version did.

I didn't notice any changes reading the paper version (but it has been a long time).  Is there a list of substantial changes (i.e. changes in the plot or characters, rather than just editing) available somewhere?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can answer this ;)

If you read the **new** HarperCollins hardcover paper version released on May 1, 2011 (as opposed to the self-published Lulu version, which is identical to the podiobook version), here's a basic list of the changes:

1. The writing itself was heavily edited and rewritten.
2. Casey's role was expanded and she now has her own intro chapter on par with Max's.
3. There are several new scenes that tie to Max Quick 2 and Max Quick 3.
4. The Tale of Enki is *greatly* shortened to keep the action flowing.
5. The entire Planet Furious scene is cut.  Reason: although kind of cool, it adds nothing dramatically and eats up precious pages.  Instead, when they pop out of the Book, Siren is waiting for them in his lab.  Which makes more sense anyway, if Siren is setting a trap, why would he not be present to spring it?
6. When Jadeth is imprisoned in the Book, she is informed immediately of what is happening, she is no longer left to figure it out.
7. When Mr. E is first encountered, he is not mirthful: he is dangerous.  The wrong question can trigger his programming to kill the asker.
8. The opening chapter introducing Max is dramatically different.

Comment: Thanks Mark!  I did indeed read the HarperCollins version (and enjoyed it all over again).

Comment: You will forever hold the spot as the first author to answer a question about his own work on our site. Kudos. :) I sincerely hope you check back every so often. Maybe you have questions of your own you'd like to ask?

Comment: DampeS8N: That is pretty cool and glad to hear that! :) Been a fan of Stackoverflow and associated products for a long time and when a Google Alert showed me the question when it was posted, I figured I'd mosey over and answer :)  And yes I will check around now that I know about the SciFi / Fantasy section of Stack products.